# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'numberchoices' was corrupted

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am having this terminal error every time I finish the debug program.

What I am doing:

[this program is a simple Lottery Numbers Comparison between user input numbers with the non-repeated random lottery numbers. e.g. using what if it got 4 right of 6]

but it turns out that the program is not working or at least, be stable.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
cout << "[La Loteria Electronica]\n";
cout << "Escoge 6 n" << char(163) << "meros del (1 al 49): \n";
int numberchoices[] = { 0 };

for (int w = 1; w < 7; w++)
{
    cout << "N" << char(163) << "mero #" << w << ": ";
    cin >> numberchoices[w];
} // user numbers



    //lottery numbers
    int i, j, k, nums[51];
    srand((int)time(0));
    for (i = 1; i < 50; i++) nums[i] = i;
    for (i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        j = (rand() % 49) + 1;
        k = nums[i]; nums[i] = nums[j]; nums[j] = k;
    }
    cout << "The lottery numbers are:  ";
    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) cout << nums[i] << " ";

    if (numberchoices[i] = nums[i])
    {
        cout << "gud\n";
    }

    if (numberchoices == nums)
    {
        cout << "gud 2";
    }
  /**/




cout << "\n\n";
system("pause");
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0 btw.

Comment: @RetiredNinja PROGRAMMING MEME ALERT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ?

```
int numberchoices[] = { 0 };

for (int w = 1; w < 7; w++)
{
    cout << "N" << char(163) << "mero #" << w << ": ";
    cin >> numberchoices[w];
} // user numbers
```

You're declaring an array of size 1 and then you use it up to position 6 ?

> I am having this terminal error every time I finish the debug program.

I'm surprised that you're not having a terminal error every time you start debug.

The access of `numberchoises` at positions from 1 to 6 are UB (Undefined Behavior). That is: all can happens.

Solution: try with

```
int numberchoices[7] = { }; // initialize all elements to zero!
```

Another point

```
if (numberchoices == nums)
```

not sure that you get what do you expect.

Do you want compare the integer pointer corresponding to `numberchoices` (a `int[1]`, suggested `int[7]`) with the one corresponding to `nums` (a `int[51]`) ?

Comment: Ok, I tried putting all the arrays to zero, before I saw your edit and still gave me that error. 

and it works flawlessly. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am in Advanced Programming Class and still, I feel like I'm from basic xD

Comment: @KoranJMirandaViera - answer improved: not sure about `if (numberchoices == nums)`

Comment: What I expect at least is "If the user numbers are equal to the lottery numbers, then it's something

Comment: but for some instance, "what if only 4 matched out of the lottery numbers?" 

That's what I want to accompish.

Comment: @KoranJMirandaViera - so do you want compare two different arrays? But they are of different size. Anyway, not through `numberchoices == nums`.

Comment: Oh, I see! So the solution is comparing through array positions/pointers if I am correct.

Comment: @KoranJMirandaViera - isn't clear to me what do you want. Anyway, if you want compare two array of the same size, I suggest you the use of `std::array` (that define `operator==`); otherwise... I don't know.